# Get the value of the button chosen using J-Query from MVC Razor Page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I have created a loop in an MVC Razor Page to create the number of buttons based on a category, but have not figured out how to get the value, which is a count number and the label of the button chosen as of yet.
How do you get the value of the button and Label of the button chosen?

```
      [Code]
           //MVC Razor View Page:

             //Loop to Get Dictionary List Buttons with Distinct Section Values.
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Section.Count; i++)
                {
                    // var Count = i;
                    <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" value=@Model.Section[i].Value id="ddlSectionButtons" , new { onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" } />

                }
                
               //Controller:

               Section = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                           where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                           select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),
                                 

                 //Model: 

                      public List<SelectListItem> SectionList { get; set; }
                      public List<SelectListItem> Section { get; set; }

                //J-Query: (It only gets the first button label, but not the chosen?)
               
                //Capture the current ddlSection. 
                 $(".ddlSectionButtons").each(function () {
                 $("body").on("click", ".ddlSectionButtons", function () {
                 var ddlSectionButtons = $('#ddlSectionButtons').val();
                 if ($('.ddlSectionButtons').val() != null) {
                 alert("Section: " + ddlSectionButtons);
                };
              });
            });

                              [/Code]
```

J-Query only gets the first button and does not return the correct value, but only the first value, and need it to also return the count number generated through the loop.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `id` should be unique . To fix this you can use `$(this).val()` instead of  `$('#ddlSectionButtons').val()`

Comment: "the count number generated through the loop" What's the count? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use only `onclick="focusMe(this)"`,so that you can get the current input in the function.Here is a working demo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Section.Count; i++)
                {
                    // var Count = i;
                    <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" value=@Model.Section[i].Value id=@i class="ddlSectionButtons" onclick="focusMe(this)"/>

                }
```

js:

```
function focusMe(t) { 
     var count=$(t).attr("id");
     var ddlSectionButtons = $(t).val();
    if (ddlSectionButtons != null) {
        alert("Section: " + ddlSectionButtons);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get the value of the button: $("body").on("click", ".ddlSectionButtons", function () {
        var ddlSectionButtons = $(this).closest('#ddlSectionButtons').val();
        if ($('.ddlSectionButtons').val() != null) {
            alert("Section: " + ddlSectionButtons);
        };
    });